# Async and Await issue in c#

Tags: c#

I need help in making my method asynchronous:

This is the method, which works fine now, but if I remove GetAwaiter().GetResult() , I don't get the values and I am told that GetAwaiter().GetResult() is not a good practice. So I would like to know, how I am going to change it to make it asynchronous. If i write internal async Task , I get error from my other methods from where its being called as return type is not correct. How do I fix it?

```
internal string GeneratePartitionKey( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg)
        {      
            var partitionKey = RunScript( PSScript, filter );
            return partitionKey.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }


 public async Task<string> RunScript( string scriptContents, List<string> scriptParameters )
        {string script = @"Get-ChildItem C:\ ";
            using( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
            {                
                ps.AddScript( script );
                var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach( var item in pipelineObjects )
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine( item.BaseObject.ToString() );
                }
                  return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }            
        }
```

//We start from here where error happens on changing GeneratePartitionKey to async

```
 await csvCopy.UploadNonCsvData( rule.GeneratePartitionKey,rule.GenerateRowKey, unzipper, schemaFormat, true, csvSchema );
        

public async Task UploadNonCsvData( Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genPartitionKey,
            Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genRowKey,
            Stream lines, string format, bool upsert, IDataClassifier classifier )
        {
            var dataclass = classifier.Classes.Where( c => c.Format.Equals( format, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ).FirstOrDefault();

            await WriteToTable( lines, dataclass,
                genPartitionKey,
                genRowKey, upsert );
        }

public async Task WriteToTable( Stream lines, DataClass dataclass,
        Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genPartitionKey,
        Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genRowKey, bool upsert )
    {
        const int BatchSize = 100;
        if( HasPartitionAndRowKey( dataclass.TableSchema.Fields ) )
        {
            genPartitionKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props ) => props["PartitionKey"].StringValue;
            genRowKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props ) => props["RowKey"].ToString();
        }
        
        var tableRecords = ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields )
            .Select( props => new DynamicTableEntity( genPartitionKey( props ), genRowKey( props ), string.Empty, props ) )
            .ToList();
        await BatchInsertIntoTableStorage( BatchSize, tableRecords, upsert );

    }

 private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>> ReadCSV( Stream source, IEnumerable<TableField> cols )
        {
            using( TextReader reader = new StreamReader( source, Encoding.UTF8 ) )
            {....... while( csv.Read() )
                {
                    yield return map.ToDictionary(
                        col => col.Name,
                        col => EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject( csv.GetField( col.Type, col.Index ) ) );
                }
            }




private async Task BatchInsertIntoTableStorage( int batchSize, List<Task<DynamicTableEntity>> tableEntries, bool upsert )
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;


        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( _account ) && string.IsNullOrEmpty( _key ) )
        {
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        }
        else
        {
            storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
                             new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.StorageCredentials( _account, _key ),
                             true );
        }

        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference( _table );

        foreach( var tableEntryBatch in tableEntries.Batch( batchSize ) )
        {
            var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
            foreach( var tableEntry in tableEntryBatch )
                batchOperation.Add( upsert ? TableOperation.InsertOrReplace((ITableEntity) tableEntry ) : TableOperation.Insert((ITableEntity) tableEntry ) );

            await table.ExecuteBatchAsync( batchOperation );
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: `async` / `await` rises to the top of the call stack, and ideally you should allow it to do so, only blocking at the top-most level.

Comment: To avoid the whole issue of Sync-over-Async (which is what this is), you could try creating a non-async version of `RunScript`. I did not look however to determine for sure that there are non-async versions of all the methods that you are using.

Comment: Ideally you would change signature to `internal async Task<string> GeneratePartitionKey` and change any calling mathods to async etc

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay "only blocking at the top-most level. " why blocking? the top most level should be an event of type `async void`. Which should not block

Comment: @PeterB B creating non async version of RunScript is easy but I would like to mke it async

Comment: changing signature causes error on line where i am calling the method, see in question, it says return type does nt matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `GeneratePartitionKey` to an async method:

```
internal Task<string> GeneratePartitionKey( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg)
{      
   var partitionKey = RunScript( PSScript, filter );
   return await partitionKey;
}
```

In order to avoid compile errors, you have to change the type of your delegate to `Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, Task<string>>`:

```
public async Task UploadNonCsvData( Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, Task<string>> genPartitionKey,
            Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genRowKey,
            Stream lines, string format, bool upsert, IDataClassifier classifier )
        {
            var dataclass = classifier.Classes.Where( c => c.Format.Equals( format, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ).FirstOrDefault();

            await WriteToTable( lines, dataclass,
                genPartitionKey,
                genRowKey, upsert );
        }

public async Task WriteToTable( Stream lines, DataClass dataclass,
        Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, Task<string>> genPartitionKey,
        Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string> genRowKey, bool upsert )
    {
        const int BatchSize = 100;
        if( HasPartitionAndRowKey( dataclass.TableSchema.Fields ) )
        {
            genPartitionKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props ) => Task.FromResult(props["PartitionKey"].StringValue);
            genRowKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props ) => props["RowKey"].ToString();
        }
        
        var csv = ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields );
        var tableRecords = new List<DynamicTableEntity>();
        foreach(var entry in csv)
        {
            tableRecords.Add(new DynamicTableEntity( await genPartitionKey( props ), genRowKey( props ), string.Empty, props );
        }
        await BatchInsertIntoTableStorage( BatchSize, tableRecords, upsert );

    }
```

Comment: then I get error on WriteTotable method at genpartitionKey() saying cannot convert type string to task<string>

Comment: @zzzsharepoint are you sure you included the "async" and  "await" bits?

Comment: @MarcGravell Gotcha :)

Comment: yes i am getting error at the lambda expression in WriteToTable method

Comment: might be because of ReadCsv method, I have included that in the question now, please check and suggest

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint I changed the code so that the `tableRecords` list is not built with LINQ anymore, but with a foreach loop. This should be less error prone.

Comment: tried and now I get error as Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity]' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.ITableEntity'.. In WriteToTable There is BatchInsert() which cause the error. included that as well in question now

Answer (score 0):

[See this article about the GetAwaiter().GetResult()](https://gsferreira.com/archive/2020/08/avoid-getawaiter-getresult-at-all-cost/)

Avoid at all cost using ".GetAwaiter().GetResult()", ".Result" or ".Wait()".
Refactor the method "GeneratePartitionKey" to be asynchrouns.

And then the LINQ expression would be something similar to this:

```
var tableRecors = (await Task.WhenAll(ReadCSV(lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields)
                            .Select( props =>
                                    new DynamicTableEntity(genPartitionKeyAsync(props), genRowKey(props), string.Empty, props)
                                ))).Where(result => result != null).ToList();
```

Comment: tried and now I get error as Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity]' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.ITableEntity'.. In WriteToTable There is BatchInsert() which cause the error. included that as well in question now